# Cast list to list of superclass

Tags: .net, f#

Say I define the following interface and class implementing it:

```
type IGreeter =
  abstract member GetGreeting: unit -> string

type Human =
  interface IGreeter with
    member this.GetGreeting () = "Why hello there"
```

Great. And say I have a `list<Human>` somewhere. Now, the problem is, how do I convert that to a `list<IGreetable>`? Example:

```
let humans: Human list = ...
let greeters: IGreeter = (upcast humans)
```

This gives both a warning and an error:

`Warning FS0059: The type 'IGreeter list' does not have any proper subtypes and need not be used as the target of a static coercion`

`Error FS0193: Type constraint mismatch. The type Human list is not compatible with type IGreeter list The type 'IGreeter' does not match the type 'Human'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the specification states, F# does not support generic variance:

**14.5.2 Solving Subtype Constraints**

> Note: F# generic types do not support covariance or contravariance.
>   That is, although single-dimensional array types in the CLI are
>   effectively covariant, F# treats these types as invariant during
>   constraint solving. Likewise, F# considers CLI delegate types as
>   invariant and ignores any CLI variance type annotations on generic
>   interface types and generic delegate types.

You'll have to cast the elements of the list and create a new one:

```
let greeters = humans |> List.map (fun h -> h :> IGreeter)
```